# Bullets instantiate inside wall, doesn't trigger OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

I use this script. All is ok, but if my `bullet` spawns **in** `Wall`, it doesn't react with wall. It flies inside the wall. 
So, what should I use for instan destroy bullet if it spawns *inside* wall?

Bullet spawn method:

```
Instantiate(bullet1, firepoint1.position, firepoint1.rotation);
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a correct behaviour? I mean, should your bullet spawn inside the wall? You could spawn it inside your tank and put them in separate layers so that the tank and the bullet don't collide. That should avoid the bullet to spawn in front of the tank and probably inside something. You can look for Collision Layer Matrix in the physics2D options for your project.

Comment: What should I do in Layer Collision Matrix?

Comment: You can put the tank in a layer A, the bullet in a layer B and in the matrix you set that A don't collide with B, so you can spawn the bullet inside the tank safely, without taking the risk to spawn it in front of the tank (and probably inside the wall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since colliders are giving troubles when the GameObject is instantiated inside the other collider. I recommed you to first check if the bullet would be instantiated inside the Wall, and in that case, directly don´t instantiate it. I believe this will make the code more efficient.

So first you need to add the Wall in a Layer ([Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR-Tf_6uzwc) you can see how to create a new layer and assign the wall to that layer). An pass it as parameter to the script you use to instantiate the bullets (the script of the tank for example).

```
public LayerMask wallLayer;
```

You save the transform of the tank in a variable

```
// Variable with position of the Tank
Transform _transform;

void Awake () {

    _transform = GetComponent<Transform> ();

}
```

Next thing you generate `Physics2D.Linecast`. [Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Linecast.html). Assuming you use a script attached to the tank GameObject to fire the bullets:

```
// Linecase goes from the tank position to the place where you would be instantiating the bullet
boolean insideWall = Physics2D.Linecast(_transform.position, firepoint1.position, wallLayer);
```

Then you instantiate the bullet only in case you would not instantiate it inside the wall.

```
if(!insideWall)
    Instantiate(bullet1, firepoint1.position, firepoint1.rotation);
```